# Default Settings in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, system-settings

How can I reset all settings for the system preferences in Mac OS X? I'm using lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post, from the official Apple Support Forums, regarding the exact question, after a quick google search on the topic:
[Official Apple Support Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3198776?start=0&tstart=0)

> I have been able to accomplish this via the following method. I may
>   not be the best idea given it deletes the account while logged in, but
>   worked for me.
>
> 1) Do all of the necessary installations, etc. just as under Snow Leopard, using your setupacctname account.
>
> 2) Once that is done, BEFORE restarting in single user mode:
>        sudo su
>        dscl . -delete /Groups/admin GroupMembership setupacctname
>        dscl . -delete /Users/setupacctname
>   3) Reboot into single user mode (Hold Command-s at startup)
>   4) Check the filesystem: /sbin/fsck -fy
>   5) Mount the filesystem: /sbin/mount -uw /
>   6) Remove the setupacctname directory: rm -R /Users/setupacctname
>   7) Remove or rename .AppleSetupDone so you get the language choice
>
> ```
>  cd /var/db/
>  mv .AppleSetupDone .RunLanguageChooserToo   or
>
>  rm .AppleSetupDone
> ```
>
> 8) Delete miscellaneous files (unnecessary, but useful if you're imaging the drive):
>
> ```
>  rm -R /Library/Caches/*
>  rm -R /System/Library/Caches/*
>  rm -R /var/vm/swapfile*
> ```
>
> 9) Shutdown or restart

Comment: Wow, that was quite something. I almost peed my pants. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you're also looking to reset application settings (and the arrangement of Dock icons and so on), you could try running this in Terminal:

```
rm -r ~/Library/Preferences/*
```

Missing preference files will just be recreated so it should be harmless. I've done it a few times on test accounts and haven't run into any issues.

Comment: You would also need to remove the ~/Library/Application Support/ folder. Even that won't get *everything* (some settings are saved as /Library/Preferences/ and such) but it will probably get close enough.